"gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found." Wut?
So ive been trying to get ubuntuu in a virtual-box VM with Kali linux apps installed because installing Kali directly was not working for multiple reasons. I fount this  tutorial of how to install Kali apps using something called Katoolin3.  everything was going great until  I tried adding something called a "key" I dont know what that is but the guide said to run this with root privilege:  wget -q -o - https:\\archive.kali.org\archive-key.asc | apt-key add But The key wasn't added and I got this: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. I have no idea what this means. The guy in the guide didint get it either and don't know what to do...

Note that whereas the "time lapse" shows the command as wget -q -o - https:\\archive.kali.org\archive-key.asc | apt-key add what is actually typed in the video is wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add - note in particular the case of the -O option and the direction of the slashes

Oh that was the problm
